# Smooth 60fps frame rate independent motion in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, frame-rate

I'm having trouble achieving frame rate independent motion in AS3 at 60fps. Every frame I measure the time since the previous frame, add it to an accumulator, and if the accumulator is greater than my target time, which is 16.666ms (60fps), a frame is simulated.

The problem is that the AS3 getTimer() only returns a time in milliseconds.

The delta times I get are often 16ms for the first frame, 16ms for the second, then 18ms for the third, and this pattern repeats. This averages out to 16.666. But in the first frame it is lower than the target time (16 < 16.666), so no frame is simulated. In the second frame the accumulator is higher than the target time, but slightly less than double it, so one frame is simulated. For the third frame 18ms pushes the accumulator over double the target time, so two frames are simulated.

So I'm getting this very jerky motion where no frames are rendered, then one, then two, then none, then one, then two, and this continues.

How would I get around this?

Comment: I suggest reading this article: http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/

Comment: Why are you using Timer and not Event.ENTER_FRAME ?

Answer (score 1):

Wow... I thought I was only one who found that out.

Yes, the timer class in AS3 is not accurate.  It will only trigger every ~16ms which causes MAJOR issues at times.

> If want to see **2048 actions in 1000ms**: [FlashText Markup Language](http://reshapemedia.com/ftml/)

**(To test this, you'll need a method which takes 1ms to execute - just for even stats)**

Notice the difference:

> **CORRECT**: 1000ms | timer=0 == 1000 actions
>
> **AS3**: 1000ms | timer=0 == 62.5 actions

I was able to write a class that works like this:

> **CORRECT**: 1000ms | timer=0 == 1000 actions
>
> **RESHAPE TIMER**: 1000ms | timer=0 == 1024 actions

NOTE:

> 1. it **DOES NOT** fire an action every ms
> 2. it **DOES** catch up to actions between the 16ms interval
> 3. an ACTION (the way I use it) is a method call, each method call can have its own body

The methodology I used to create this was catch-up... basically the first timer event will fire at 16ms... we know we have a full 16ms worth of code time to fire our own actions before the timer class fires again - thats where you inject sub-actions...

The highest I was able to produce was 2048 actions in 1000ms... **more than 2 actions per ms**.

**Now... back to your problem**
There is NO WAY to trigger a 0ms timer event.  Based on my solution, if you want to by-pass the first 16ms of lag before the timer fires... you can dispatch an event which will fire within 2ms depending on the current system processes.

**Possible Solution**
If you take my approach for throwing your own actions within the 16ms, then you can build your own timer class.  Use events for times under 16ms, when fired... fire 15 more - lol.  Basically, you can create your own deltas between the 16ms.